# Maven tomcat7:run for multi-module project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

We have a multi-module Maven project: `project-war` depends on `project-api`.

I have imported the modules into IntelliJ, and I would like to use `tomcat7:run` to run run the `project-war` application in Tomcat. I do so, the application runs fine.

I make a change to `project-api`, stop Tomcat, restart Tomcat. The `project-war` application runs again fine, but the changes to `project-api` are not reflected as expected.

How to get the transitive changes from my workspace to be reflected when running `tomcat7:run`?

---

I've tried "`Resolve Workspace artifacts`". It didn't help. In fact, I don't get this setting at all.

I've tried "`Before launch:`" "`Make`". It does what appears to be a build (compile) but it didn't help either.

I think what I"m looking for is pretty much what m2e/Eclipse calls *workspace resolution*. Can't get it to work in IntelliJ. Your help much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried mvn clean tomcat7:run?

Comment: It really only affects "`project-war`", wouldn't it? It doesn't involve "`project-api`"?

Comment: What is the whole project structure?

Comment: I have the same problem, but i think is not something related to Intellij. I think tomcat7-maven-plugin attempts to load the installed maven dependencies (not from workspace, but from the maven repository). If you run "clean install" in yout api project, then tomcat7:run will load the updated project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/keesvandieren/intellij-tomcat7-run-workspace-resolution) is a good repository to test this out.

As it turns out, this problem existed using IntelliJ 12.1.7, but not anymore using IntelliJ 13.1.5.

Workspace resolution works with a combination of the described configuration:

- `Resolve Workspace Artifacts`
- `Before launch:` `Make`

Comment: Hi I meet the same problem, I tried what you mentioned, but it does not work, how do you solve it?

Comment: I told you how I solved it (these two settings on the right version of IntelliJ). Beyond that we're right back at debugging this.

Comment: I respect your observation, but for me it _does_ work. We are also on 14.1(.5) now and having no (new) problems. Does the [linked repository](https://github.com/keesvandieren/intellij-tomcat7-run-workspace-resolution) work for you, since it's a pretty isolated example? It might be worthwhile for you to just create a new question, that describes your exact problem and what the things are that you tried. (Please drop a link here to that question, since I'd be interested to follow it.)